# What's the name of the heresy that declares Mary Mother of God is a goddess?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary

Such heresy was condemned centuries ago by the Church, but I cannot remember its name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The heresy is known as **Collyridianism,** after the Greek for the "little cakes" which were offered.

> Collyridianism was an obscure Early Christian heretical movement whose adherents apparently worshipped the Virgin Mary, mother of Jesus, as a goddess. The main source of information about them comes from their strongest opponent, Epiphanius of Salamis, who wrote about them in his *Panarion* of about 375 AD. According to Epiphanius, certain women in then-largely-pagan Arabia syncretized indigenous beliefs with the worship of Mary, and offered little cakes or bread-rolls (Greek κολλυρις – a word occurring in the Septuagint) to her. Epiphanius states that Collyridianism originated in Thrace and Scythia, although it may have first travelled to those regions from Syria or Asia Minor. Little else is known.
>
> [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collyridianism)